# Why is the torrent download for 21.10 only 233K?

Tags: downloads

I usually upgrade my Ubuntu desktops by reinstalling from a .iso.
I usually download the .iso using a torrent server on my Asus router. That way I can help to spread the good news.
But now with 21.10 the torrent .iso is only 233K. It's not the actual .iso
The .iso version is 2.9GB.
What's going on?
Thanks.

Answer (score 7):

The `.torrent` file is 233K.  This is a torrent seed file that provides the information about the torrent to your torrent client.  It is **not** the Ubuntu ISO.

The `.ISO` file downloaded by your torrent client using this seed is identical to the ISO you would download directly from the website.